# Django database query returning fewer than requested results

Tags: python, django

My Django database query is returning a maximum of 10 results even though the database has 22 records that satisfy the query.

I pick up the number of results wanted from a Django REST Framework api call. My code looks like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    quantity = self.request.query_params.get('num', 20)
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(active=True, credits_left__gt=0)[0:int(quantity)]
    return queryset
```

If I make the call with any number up to 10 I get the number of results I requested back as expected. With any number over 10 I still get 10 results. I can't see what I am doing wrong here. Is there a Django default limit set somewhere that I don't know about?

Comment: Maybe some pagination setting that limits the results. Have you tried to add 'page=2' or 'page=3' as get params?

Comment: Did you double check that you actually have more than 10 records that satisfy the query?

Comment: Yes there are 22 records that satisfy the query.

Comment: I don't want to page the results I would like to be able to return more than 10 results in one go.

Comment: Pass limit & offset as get parameters. I think some pagination is happenning. It is limiting the default count to 10..

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: It is the ModelViewSet that is doing automatic pagination via ListModelMixin. I need to find a way to turn this off.